# How to inject @Value constructor parameter using Mockito annotation

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a class:

```
public class MyClass{
    MyClass(
            @Value("${my.protocol}") String protocol,
            @Value("${my.host}") String host,
            @Value("${my.port}") int port,
            @Autowired MyService myservice) {
        ........
    }

    ....

}
```

I then wrote a test that uses Mockito:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyClassTest {

    @Mock
    private MyService myservice;

    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClass;

    ....
}
```

The test failed with this:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
Cannot instantiate @InjectMocks field named 'myClass'! Cause: the type 'MyClass ' has no default constructor
You haven't provided the instance at field declaration so I tried to construct the instance.
Examples of correct usage of @InjectMocks:
   @InjectMocks Service service = new Service();
   @InjectMocks Service service;
   //and... don't forget about some @Mocks for injection :)
```

I think this is because I only provided one of the 4 construction parameters, not the other three which has @Value annotation.

Can someone please let me know how I can inject the three @Value construction parameters in order for this to work?

I use Junit 5 and Mockito.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Annotation-based magic is showy, but it's not the solution to every problem. Just do things the old-fashioned way:

```
@BeforeEach
void setup() {
  this.subject = new MyClass("http", "localhost", 5000, mockService);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mockito uses reflection inorder to initialize your instances so there will be no injection happening at the initialization step, it'll simply get the constructor and issue `#invoke()` method on it.

What you should do in this case is mock the values instead of mocking the whole container, the container here is `MyClass`.

I'm assuming you are using a `.yml` or a `.properties` file to assign the values, by creating a new `application-${env}.yml` this way you'll have your test values separately from the prod environment values.

Or if you have different values for each case, then before each replace the `MyClass` instance that's in the context with the one you modify:

```java
@BeforeEach
void beforeEach() {
MyClass bean =// get the context and get a reference of `MyClass` bean
bean = new MyClass(...);
}
```